# how to use remote packages on travis-ci | GO

Tags: go, travis-ci

when I run a go script ( go run example.go ) I get this error

```
/home/travis/.gvm/gos/go1.1.2/src/pkg/github.com/user/examplepackage (from $GOROOT)

/home/travis/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.1.2/global/src/github.com/user/examplepackage (from $GOPATH)
```

example.go imports a package using

```
import "github.com/user/examplepackage"
```

The `travis.yml` file looks like :

```
install:
- go get ... 

before_script:
- go run example.go
```

travis-ci team doesn't know to install and configure GOPATH and GOROOT ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `language: go` to your .travis.yml file, that way Travis CI knows that the project is a Go project and sets up the GOPATH and GOROOT correctly. [By default](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/), Travis CI runs `go get -d -v ./... && go build -v ./...` in the `install` step, so I think you may be able to change your .travis.yml to this:

```
language: go
before_script:
  - go run example.go
```

If the `go run example.go` is your test script, you should change it to this:

```
language: go
script:
  - go run example.go
```

There's more Go docs for Travis CI [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/).